# Moving google cloud instance to another zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my google-cloud project `prj1`, there's an instance `instance-1` and I want to move it from `us-central1-a` to `europe-west2` zone using the following command.

```
$ gcloud compute instances move instance-1 --zone us-central1-a --destination-zone europe-west2
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Project [prj1] not found: The resource 'projects/prj1/zones/europe-west2' was not found
```

Why does it say 'not defined' for my project?
It seems I miss some steps but I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within GCP, there is the concept of regions and zones.  A region is a geography (eg. Central US or West Europe) while zones are disparate data centers within those regions which are physically separate and hence less likely to simultaneously be down due to an event.  When we create a compute engine, we create it within a region and associated with a specific zone in that region.  Using the `gcloud compute instances move` command, we can move a compute engine from one zone to another *within the same region*.  If what you want to do is to move the instance from one region to another, this command can not be used.  Google documents a recipe for moving a compute engine from one region to another here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving_an_instance_manually

Notice in that example they are moving from `europe-west1-a` to `us-west1-b`.

See also:

- [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/)